# count calculation on the basis of date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query where I am counting values from three different tables and getting two columns, date and count from each of it. Getting 3 records for first 12 for second and 12 for third. Finally I am doing little calculation from this count columns from all these table where there date from the second column is finding a match..

For eg if date of first table column is matching with second and third one I am adding all these values and getting percentage of it… though I ‘ve created a query for it…but it is got giving correct data..

I need to know how could I perform calculation form this table on the basis of date.. I am using oracle DB

```
SELECT TRUNC(ans.date),
  (a.count1+b.count2+c.count3)*100/count4 AS status
FROM
  (SELECT COUNT(pans.actual)count1,
          TRUNC(ans.date) AS subdate
  FROM pans, ans
  WHERE pans.actres ='1'
    AND TRUNC(anss.date) > sysdate-100
    AND pans.id = anss.id
  GROUP BY TRUNC(anss.date)
  )a,
  (SELECT COUNT(conans.actres)count2,
         TRUNC(anss.date) AS subdate
  FROM conans, anss
  WHERE conans.actres ='1'
    AND TRUNC(anss.date) > sysdate-100
    AND conans.id = anss.id
  GROUP BY TRUNC(anss.date)
  )b,
  (SELECT COUNT(anss.submitted)count3,
          TRUNC(anss.date) AS subdate
  FROM anss
  WHERE submitted = 1
    AND TRUNC(anss.date) > sysdate-100
  GROUP BY TRUNC(anss.date)
  )c,
  (SELECT COUNT(pans.actres) count4
  FROM pans, anss
  WHERE anss.date > sysdate-100
  )d,
  anss,
  pans
WHERE a.subdate = b.subdate
  AND b.subdate = c.subdate
  AND a.subdate = c.subdate
  AND TRUNC(anss.date) > sysdate-100
GROUP BY TRUNC(anss.date),a.count1,b.count2,c.count3,d.count4
```

```
count1 
------------------
count |  date
3     |  12/12/1928
5     |   12/12/1998
6     |  12/12/1995
```

```
count2 
------------------
count|  date
3    |  12/12/1928
5    |   12/12/1998
6    |  12/12/1995
23   |  12/12/1924
56   |  12/12/1993
68   |  12/12/1992
39   |  12/12/1921
58   |  12/12/1990
63   |  12/12/1999
```

```
count3
------------------
count|    date
3    |  12/12/1928
5    |   12/12/1998
6    |  12/12/1995
23   |  12/12/1924
56   |  12/12/1993
68   |  12/12/1992
39   |  12/12/1921
58   |  12/12/1990
63   |  12/12/1999
```

```
count4
------------------
4500
```

now I have to calculate

```
(count1+count2+count3)*100/count4
when count1.date=count2date=count3.date
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You take all anns records of the last 100 days and cross join pans. Is this cross join desired? (It would be better you used ANSI join syntax to avoid accidental cross joins.)

You find all dates that are present in all of a, b and c and join accordingly.

You cross join the a-b-c join with your anns-pans cross join. Again: Do you really want to cross-join here? You group by anns.date (date is a bad name as it is a keyword, by the way), but what does anns.date habe to do with the records retrieved???

Syntactically your statement looks correct, but I mistrust your joins :-)